# Class keyword in front of a seem-like member function declaration

Tags: c++, lammps

I was reading the files in `LAMMPS`(An open source project),and come across this line of syntax

```
class FixPropertyGlobal* add_fix_property_global(int narg,char**arg,const char*);
```

in one of the `.h` file( `Modify.h` ) for a class declaration. My question is: **Why add the keyword class in front of a seem-like member function?** What does this syntax mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just a declaration of a global function, not a member function declaration.

That is equivalent to:

```
class FixPropertyGlobal;
FixPropertyGlobal* add_fix_property_global(int narg,char**arg,const char*);
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. Do you think I can ask you another question regarding debugging large open source project? I will open another thread on that in a bit.

Comment: @dl23lin you can certainly ask but a different SO post will be appropriate.

Comment: @dl23lin I understood what you meant.

Comment: Adding `class` is only necessary when the class hasn't been defined yet. It lets the compiler know that the function returns a pointer to some class called `FixPropertyGlobal` that will be defined later in the file. It still works if the class is defined, but is only necessary when it hasn't been.

Comment: That's useful when, for example, you have a circular dependency where class A needs to have a member of class B and vice versa. AFAIK, whichever comes first (before the definition of the second) can only have a member of type class [second class]*. Where[second class] is the name of the second class.

Comment: @Tyler These 2 comments should be an answer, one that clarifies the question.